# What if there are two paths connecting to the gold in Saboteur 2?

Tags: saboteur-2, end-game

Let's say a blue dwarf makes the final connection to the gold. However, there are two paths that one could take to get from the ladder to the gold. One of these paths has a blue door, one of them has no doors. Obviously the blue dwarf would prefer to use the path with the door, so does the player who makes the final connection get to choose what path to use? Or does it go by shortest path to the gold? Basically, what are the rules to determine what path counts as the "final path"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no such concept. The following are the win conditions for the red and blue teams from the rules:

- A team wins if a dwarf from that team creates the connection to the treasure and the way there
  isn't blocked by a door of the other color.
- A team wins if a dwarf from the other team creates the connection to the treasure, but the way there for his or her own team is blocked by a door of the wrong color.
- Both teams win if The Boss, The Geologist or The Profiteer creates the connection to the gold and the way there isn't blocked by a door of the other color.

A dwarf from the blue team created the connection, and there is a path that's not blocked by a red door, so the blue team wins, and the red team does not. That's it.

The only way the red team can win if a dwarf from the blue team creates the connection is if the blue team can't win (i.e. every path is blocked by red doors).

Comment: OK so if there are >1 possible paths at end game, and at least one of them gives the winning player a victory, then his team wins. Your last bullet brings up a follow question though: If the boss or profiteer makes the connection, and there are two connecting paths: one with a door, and one without a door, which path gets used? It seems to me the best path for the boss/profiteer would be the one with the door, because it gives them a better chance of splitting the gold with less people...but that is a little counter intuitive.

Comment: You're still assuming everyone uses a single path. As I already mentioned, there's no such concept. Blue team wins because the Boss or the Profiteer created the connection, and the way there isn't blocked by a red door. Red team wins because the Boss or the Profiteer created the connection, and the way there isn't blocked by a blue door. Nothing says they have to be the same way (path).

Comment: The Boss is better off if a Green or Blue dwarf creates the connection than if he creates it himself, as it cuts down on the number of winners. Same goes for the Profiteer and the Geologist.

Comment: I'm going to leave open for a few days just in case someone has a rebuttal, then I will pick an answer.

Comment: What rebuttal? For any dwarf who cares about reaching the treasure, they join in the win if there is a path they can take from the start point to the treasure, and that path was created by someone on their team (or the Boss/Geologist/Profiteer).

Comment: @ConMan, or if the path was created by someone on the opposing team and the opposing team can't win. (Second bullet in my answer.)

Comment: Ah yes, good point. But I completely agree with your ruling.